# Excel macro - open macro without going into Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, excel

I've finished my macro! But is there an easier way in runnning it?

I know two ways

- Open Visual Basic, select the correct macro and run!
- View Macro's, select the correct macro and run!

Is there an easier way, or are these the only two ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place a command button on your sheet, view its code in the VB editor, and edit it so it looks something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call MyMacro
End Sub
```

You can then just click your button every time you want to run your macro.

Comment: merci pour votre aide dans tous mon questions! (hope my french isn't too bad)

Answer (score 3):

you can even create little smiley icon in your Toolbar so that it stays there and you can run it by clicking it or have shortcut keys attached to it.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options:

Toolbar or Menu (Excel 2003 & earlier)

http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/how-to-assign-a-macro-to-a-toolbar-or-menu/

ActiveX control

http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/how-to-assign-a-macro-to-an-activex-control/

Button (Forms menu control) or Shape

http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/how-to-assign-a-macro-to-a-button-or-shape/